# Unable to ping docker container hosted on a different VM

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, docker-network

```
 Two docker container hosted on two different VM, port exposed to both docker container 60000. 
 Both VMs communicate through each through NAT NETWORK and not using docker 
 network compose.  Running docker-A sudo docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -v 
 $(pwd):/workdir -w /workdir tensor  
 Docker-A->172.17.0.1
 Docker-B->172.17.0.3 
 VM-A(Docker-A hosted)->172.25.1.24
 VM-B(Docker-B hosted)->172.25.1.13
```

When I try to ping from Docker-A to Docker-B I get Destination Host Unreachable error. I used ping 172.17.0.3 to connect with Docker-B. Struggling with Docker basic networking issue. Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which docker commands did you run? Or do you have a compose file? Please update your question.

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans I have updated the question. Thanks. Do you think should I use docker-compose?

Comment: Personally I prefer a declaritive approach over an imperative approach, but that shouldn't matter here. What I need is your "docker run ...." commands.

Comment: Thanks @QuintenScheppermans updated the question now included the command for running the docker container.

Comment: Seems like your formatting is a little of. I'm guessing that the first two sentences in your code block are sentences that you typed yourself to explain your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never directly use the container-private IP addresses.  In this scenario, VM A can't reach the container-private IP addresses on VM B.  There's really only two situations in which the container-private IP addresses are reachable at all, and in both cases there are better ways to do it.

Each VM is running its own Docker instance, and has its own private networking space.  While it looks like both containers have addresses in 172.17.0.0/16, they're actually separate networks, and in fact the two Docker daemons could have independently decided to assign the same IP address to both containers.  Unless you've gone out of your way to configure an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) one VM (or physical system) can't reach another server's containers by the private IP address, there's no IP route to get there.  (And in this case, since both hosts have the same IPv4 network range, VM A's route to 172.17.0.0/16 points to VM A's Docker network which is different from VM B's.)

To make a container accessible from outside Docker space, you need to launch it with a `docker run -p` option (or an equivalent Docker Compose `ports:` setting).  You can then access the container using the host's (or VM's) DNS name or IP address and the published (first) port number.  You cannot **ping**(1) a remote container this way, but there's also not any particular reason to want to send a container ICMP packets.

```
vm-a$ curl http://172.25.1.13:8888  # using vm-b's IP address
```

If the two containers were on the same host (or VM), you could [create a Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) and run both containers `--name some-name --net some-net`; if both have the same `--net some-net` then each container can reach the other using the other's `some-name` as a hostname.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) might be more approachable even if you're not using Compose; without Compose you must manually `docker network create` a network.

(I said there were two situations in which the container-private addresses work.  These are (1) from the console of the same Linux host running the containers, and (2) between containers on the same Docker network.  They do not work from other hosts, or on MacOS or Windows hosts.  The approaches above do not have these restrictions and also survive things like container-private IP addresses changing when containers are deleted and recreated.)

Comment: Thank you @David Maze working perfectly fine based on your suggestion